# What is this Java construct `(InputStream is) -> () -> {}`

Tags: java, lambda

I don't understand this Java construct that I'm seeing in the documentation here.

[public static <T,U> HttpResponse.BodySubscriber mapping(HttpResponse.BodySubscriber upstream,
Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.html#mapping(java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodySubscriber,java.util.function.Function))

The part that I think I understand but cannot seem to replicate is the example:

```
public static <W> HttpResponse.BodySubscriber<Supplier<W>> asJSON(Class<W> targetType) {
    HttpResponse.BodySubscriber<InputStream> upstream = HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.ofInputStream();
    HttpResponse.BodySubscriber<Supplier<W>> downstream = HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.mapping(
            upstream,
            (InputStream is) -> () -> {
                try (InputStream stream = is) {
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    return objectMapper.readValue(stream, targetType);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
            }
        );

    return downstream;
}
```

Specifically the `(InputStream is) -> () -> {` part. When I read it I think it should be a `Supplier` that provides a `Function` that does what it does. However, when I try to code such a thing myself it doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String r = myMethod((String s)->()->{return s + "ddd";});
}

public static String myMethod(Function<String, String> func) {
    return func.apply("Hello");
}
```

Gives me the compile err `Target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface`. However, `Function` is an interface.

What do I not understand?

Comment: It's not a `Function<String, String>`, it's a `Function<String, Supplier<String>>`

Comment: The correct syntax would be `String r = myMethod((String s)-> {return s + "ddd";});` or `String r = myMethod(s -> s + "ddd");` to make it even shorter.

Comment: @Rogue - So, you're saying I should be emulating it like so?

Comment: You could, notice the `BodySubscriber<Supplier<W>>` in the above (so the `Supplier` still goes through). This code seems _dangerous_, as it allows accessing the `InputStream` as a side-effect of the `Supplier`. The `InputStream` may be closed before the `Supplier` can generate its result, rather than getting the result directly.

Comment: A function that takes an input stream, and returns a function that takes zero arguments. I creates a closure.

Comment: Yes, this is a lambda expression within a lambda expression, you can see it through the use of two `->` tokens. In your case *`inputParam -> resultExpression`*, in which case *resultExpression* in itself is *`() -> resultExpression`*. So, yea, a `Function<String, Supplier<String>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F11%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.html#mapping(java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodySubscriber,java.util.function.Function)) takes as a 2nd parameter a value of type `Function<? super T,​? extends U>`. In your code `T` is `InputStream` and `U` is `Supplier<W>`, so the full type of `mapping` would be (ignoring the `super`\`extends` for brevity):

```java
Function<InputStream, Supplier<W>>
```

Since a `Supplier<W>` has a single method of type `W get()`, a lambda expression for the `Supplier` type would be:

```java
() -> {/* return a value of type W*/}
```

and therefore a lambda expression for `mapper` would be:

```java
(InputStream is) -> () -> {/* return a value of type W*/}
```

which matches your code.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not a Function<String, String>, it's a Function<String, Supplier>

This is a lambda expression within a lambda expression, you can see it through the use of two -> tokens. In your case inputParam -> resultExpression, in which case resultExpression in itself is () -> resultExpression. So, yea, a Function<String, Supplier>

I should be emulating it like so.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Supplier<String> r = myMethod((String s)->()->{return s + "ddd";});
}

public static Supplier<String> myMethod(Function<String, Supplier<String>> func) {
    return func.apply("Hello");
}
```

Thanks to all commenters.